# How to make requirements file with `pip` that lists package as '>='

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I would like to create a `requirements.txt` that list packages as `>=` obviously `pip freeze` does not do this.

The `pip` documentation suggests that this is not possible since there are no `list` or `freeze` options that enables different versioning specification.

Is there an easy way to affect different versioning for packages in the requirements file or is it going to be a manual task?

Comment: Why not simply create requirements.txt as per usual with `pip freeze` and then replace every `==` with `>=`?

Comment: Which is what I am doing now but it seemed like an obvious `pip` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python -c "print(subprocess.check_output('pip freeze').replace('==','>='))"
```

... i guess

Comment: Or just search replace in your favorite text editor.  But as mentioned in my previous comment, I was thinking there may be a cleaner `pip` way to achieve the same.  I guess not.

Comment: `alias pip-freeze-gt python -c "print(subprocess.check_output('pip freeze').replace('==','>='))"` ?